# How can I cat/print a file except the last 2 lines?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, sh

How can get I get the contents of a text file, except the last (for instance) 2 lines, with [standard](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/papers/posix_faq.html) or GNU shell tools? (bash, tail, cat and so on.)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-x-lines-in-bash

Comment: Anything special on those last lines, so you can use `grep(1)`?

Comment: @vonbrand, no, nothing known.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the head command from coreutils:

```
head -n -2
```

See `info head` for more.

Comment: info instead of man, daring, my good fellow. ;) +1

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: the coreutils manpages are not as well maintained as the texinfo pages, not that the head documentation differs much between the two though.

Answer (score 5):

You simply want.

```
head -n-2 file
```

Read `man head` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This command gives the whole `$file` except the last `$except` number of lines:

```
length=$(wc -l $file); head -n $((${length%% *}-except)) $file
```

(No checking whether `$except` is larger than the total number of lines of `$file`...)